# Is MVC RESTful by design

Tags: .net, wcf, model-view-controller, rest, soap

Does MVC have to be RESTful?

Is there a way to make a `SOAP` service using `MVC` pattern?

Would the input request actually go into the `View` first and then into the `Controller` then the `Model` eg:

```
Request -> View -> Controller -> Model
```

but in doing so, that's no longer MVC pattern. (that's right isn't it?)

How else would we get a typed response using `SOAP` but still adhere to (or be close to) the `MVC` pattern. Would MVVM be more suitable pattern to this situation at all instead?

Comment: I don't understand why MVC gets so much attention.

Comment: @duffymo I agree... it is not my choice

Comment: @duffymo and Seph > what technologies are you using?

Comment: I have no problem with MVC.  It has nothing to with services, REST or SOAP, because they have no view.  You're applying a buzzword/pattern where it has no business.

Comment: @duffymo the problem is my boss considers different return formats (xml/json) as 'Views'... more so he's convinced that we could just add 'html views' to our 'MVC API' and then we will have a fully working website - instead of designing the website to use the API as an API or having a custom back end or anything of that sort... now we have an API that returns html pages that make other API calls that return html pages as well. It's a mess :)

Comment: There has to be a server side component that really is part of the view.  It mediates between the client and the back end services, but it's really part of the view.  Isolate all that page generation stuff inside that and let the back end services be completely independent.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

REST describes how you interface with the application, while MVC is how you implement the application. An application implemented using MVC can be RESTful or not.

SOAP is a protocol for interfacing with the application, which can be implemented using MVC.

In MVC the request goes into the controller, which creates a model for the view.

```
Request -> [Controller] -> Model -> [View] -> Response
```

Comment: for typed SOAP to work (eg: WSDL), you would still need to wrap the request in a type safe wrapper, no?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP was designed to be RESTful. Detailed discussion about what is REST was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming). MVC has no restriction about to be RESTful or not. ASP.Net MVC supports REST style of web development. You can make you web site RESTful or not, it's your choice. SOAP is protocol. In .Net is better to use WCF to deal with SOAP. WCF services can be deployed together with your ASP.Net MVC application. But we do not have MVC implementation inside WCF. In general we don't have UI part in Web / WCF services at all.

Answer (score 0):

The request is routed to an action on your controller, which uses a model (which you define; it's merely a structure that represents the data that your action and view will operate on). This action returns an `ActionResult`, which often is, but does not have to be, a `ViewResult` (which essentially just executes the view page you specified, using the model you specified, if any). However, you don't have to return a View; You can create any sort of ActionResult you want. You can return XML, JSON, SOAP, binary content, whatever.

MVC is restful in nature, but it is not strictly adherent to REST and can be tailored to whatever you see fit. You could have your controller speak SOAP, but my question is why would you, if that work is already done for you in other technologies (such as WCF)?