# Rest service architecture

Tags: web-services, rest, architecture

I've just completed the "Getting Started with RESTful Web Services" tutorial on NetBeans. So basically, I created a restful service from a database and deployed it, ready for a client to consume.No frameworks or anything were used. A Web Application was created and a rest service from a database was added to it.

Edit: I've also created a very basic Javascript client with a GUI that can access the service.

My question is, what architecture is this project using? It's a RESTful, but is it using MVC/MVVM etc.? How would you describe the architecture within the service?

Comment: You don't have anything but some RESTful services. The webapp is needed/created to run a JAX-RS application. MV* Just describe a UI design pattern, for which you have described no UI. If you decide to add some web front end using the REST services and follows RESTful patterns, then you can ultimately say you have a RESTful web application

Comment: Ok. I've since created a restful Javascript client with a GUI and it can access the service. Would that describe an architecture? Sorry for the silly questions, I've looked this up online but it's difficult because I know what I'm looking for exactly.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/153581/95894) might answer your question.

Comment: If you are interested in the connection between REST and MVC, you can google "rest mvc pattern". There you might find what you're looking for. For example [here is one of the first results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275613/is-mvc-restful-by-design)